# Cannot call `setTimeout` because function [1] requires another argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I'm getting a flow (incompatible-call) error when setting `someProp` to a `setTimeout`. The error states that I cannot call `setTimeout` because function [1] requires another argument. I'm not sure what this means, and I need help! The code worked before I tried to "flow" it. TIA!

```js
// @flow

import React, { Component } from 'react';

type Props = {
  someProp: TimeoutID,
};

export default class MyClass extends Component<Props> {

  someProp: ?TimeoutID;

  resetState = (i: number) => {
    this.setState({ ... });
    delete this.someProp;
  };

  onMouseLeave = () => {
    this.someProp = setTimeout(this.resetState, 300); // <- error
  };

  render() {}
}
```

Comment: `resetState` requires parameter `i`, which you are not providing. You may need to provide it, e.g. `setTimeout(() => this.resetState(0), 300);`.

Comment: You have to pass `setTimeout` a parameterless function and `resetState` has 1 parameter.

Comment: The third argument to setTimeout would be useful for this scenario, assuming typescript can put 2 and 2 together

Comment: @ScottMarcus No; see Arrow Function Syntax. `() => ...` is a shorter version of the same thing.

Comment: I figured out the problem! The thing was that I actually "wanted" to have no argument, and the fact that I had set the argument to be a number screwed it up! Thanks for the feedback though guys! <3

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Right, I didn't even notice the arrow function part.